# Can set each token for each user in oauth asp.net webapi?

Tags: c#, oauth, token, webapi

I'm using OAuth authentication for Web apis. Now, a **user1** will gets a token when requesting with valid username and password. And then **user2** can access another authorized function (here testwithsametoken) in the system with **same token**. I have to restrict the users using the token of another user. How can I achieve this? I'm using granttype=password when requesting the token

Startup.cs

```
  public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        var OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/get_token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };

        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```

SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider.cs

```
     [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public eRMS_BLClass1 objLogic = new eRMS_BLClass1();
        public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated(); //   
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
        var user = objLogic.CheckUserLogin(context.UserName, context.Password);
        if (user == 0)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Provided username and password is incorrect");
            context.Rejected();
        }
        else
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
            context.Validated(identity);//get token
        }
        return;
    }
    }
```

app.Controllers

```
[Route("CheckUserLogin"), HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        public HttpResponseMessage CheckUserLogin(string staff_id, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                var Response = objLogic.CheckUserLogin(staff_id, password);
                var Result = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Response, new 
                 JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
                return Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                HttpError Error = new HttpError(ex.Message) { { "IsSuccess", false } };
                return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Error);
            }
        }

        [Route("testwithsametoken"), HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        public HttpResponseMessage testwithsametoken()
        {
            try
            {
                var Response = objLogic.testwithsametoken();
                var Result = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Response, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
                return Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HttpError Error = new HttpError(ex.Message) { { "IsSuccess", false } };
                return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Error);
            }
        }
```

Comment: each user would have their own token

Comment: But with the above code, using the token of user1, user2 can access the function 'testwithsametoken'

Comment: why would user2 have access to user1's token? the token grants the access, each authenticated user would be issued with a valid token, if another user gets access to their token they would be able to use it, that is why you need to protect the tokens over https etc

Comment: It is for security testing of my application.

Comment: You can't. Simply because the only user information you have is the token itself. You can't tell if it is user1 or user2 executing the request.